# Set values from Array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variables, valueerror

I am trying to set the value from an array into specific values.  little lost.  Get this error from python;
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

```
n=2
a = np.zeros((n,2))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        a [i][j] = [[3,1], 
                    [1,3]]
```

Comment: `a[i,j]` indexes a single float slot in the array.  You can't fill it with a list (of lists)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you trying to accomplish but you should set the array element with one single value like this:

```
import numpy as np
n=2 
a = np.zeros((n,2)) 
for i in range(n): 
   for j in range(n): 
       a [i][j] = 5
```

Or simply define it with the values you want:

```
import numpy as np
n=2 
a = np.zeros((n,2)) 
a[0:2,0:2] = [[3,1], 
              [1,3]]
```